# Best Practice for Firebase Rules to allow task creator and responsible user to modify task

Tags: security, firebase

I have implemented a tree structure for root projects and the tasks required. A task has a notes, complete, due-date and may have a user-id responsible for the task.

I am using email/password authentication. The structure is:

```
{
  "rules":{
    "users":{
      "$user-id":{ 
          ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
         "tasks":{
           "task":{
               // allow auth.uid = value of primeID

           }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to restrict modification of a task record to a user with "isAdmin==true", the creator or the responsible user-id (if one exists) and would appreciate help.

Comment: Did you try anything yet? If so, show us the rules you've tried so that we can improve on that instead of starting from scratch.

Comment: I edited rules above and have received advice that I should look at custom tokens in order to handle "isAdmin" so I am going to proceed with that and update this with the final result. Thanks